# Visual Studio 2015 Adds Namespace in front of class names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I hit a statement completion key (not sure what they're called), VS adds the namespace in front of the class.

So when I hit the "(" for statement completion, I get

```
//Don't want the namespace "Models" preceding "Category1"
List<Category1> test1 = new List<Models.Category1>();
```

instead of what I'd like:

```
List<Category1> test1 = new List<Category1>();
```

I have a `using` already in the class file.
I think the issue started with Update 3. Can't find anything in `Tools > Options` to shut this off. Anyone know how to change this behavior?

**Edit** I should mention that if I hit the `tab` key, this does not happen. I could just hit the `tab` key, but it's an extra keystroke, and muscle memory, etc...

**Update**
The full code in `Program.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestStatementCompletion.Models;

namespace TestStatementCompletion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Category1> test1 = new List<Models.Category1>();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My folder structure]

Comment: Are you sure `Model` is a namespace, and not a class that has a nested class in it?

Comment: Are you `using`(importing) the `Model` namespace?

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes, it's all my code

Comment: @JoshPart Yes, I have the namespace

Comment: Is there any conflicting class? For example, is there another `Category` class in a different namespace that is also in your `using` section or in your current namespace hierarchy? If you manually remove `Model.`, does it still compile properly?

Comment: @JoeEnos No, nothing like that. I made a little sample application, `Category` is the only class I have in the project.

Comment: "I made a little sample application" -- Is it small enough to just post the whole thing here? Also, just erase `Model.`, what does it say when you do that?

Comment: There's nothing to it, a console application with a folder `Model`, a class in that folder `Category`, and in `static void Main`, the above line.

Comment: Yea I get this when i put the class in a folder with the exact same name. If that the case just change the folder name

Comment: @AlexKrupka Ok, will try that right now

Comment: Related to @AlexKrupka's comment, if you create a folder in VS then create a class inside that folder, VS automatically names the namespace after the folder. You can just rename the namespce in the code without messing with the folder name. E.g., I just made a "test" folder, and created a class called "testing", and VS automatically did this with the code: `namespace ConsoleApplication6.test { class testing` -- I just erase ".test" from the namespace name when it does this.

Comment: @AlexKrupka Spun up a new console app, named the folder `Models`, same behavior

Comment: @MichaelTranchida Please provide the code and folder structure for review.

Comment: @Quantic I usually want my namespaces to reflect my folder structure

Comment: @DipenShah That is the code. Do I really need to wrap `var cats = new List<Model.Category>();` with `static void Main(string[] args) { }`?

Comment: Then I assume you have a folder named "Model", and a .cs file in that folder with your "Category" class in it, and the file has `namespace ProjectName.Model` as the namespace, so unless you are `using ProjectName.Model` at the top of your other source file you *have* to have `Model.Category`. Show us your code so I can verify my assumptions.

Comment: @Quantic Ok, hold on one second

Comment: Do you have ReSharper or another plugin?

Comment: @JoeEnos Um. yes, several. Productivity Power Tools, CodeMaid, C# Essentials, MultiEditing look like the only ones that would mess with my code.

Comment: @JoeEnos Just double-checked these extensions in `Tools > Options` and don't see anything where I could affect this behavior.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida How come compiler complains on 
new List<Models.Category1>() 

but not on List<Category1> test1.

Comment: @DipenShah The compier doesn't complain. It's that when I hit the "(" to complete the statement, the editor adds the namespace automatically. VS did not used to do this. I hit the "(" right after typing `List<Category1> test1 = new `, when the intellisense pops up for suggestions.

Comment: I think is best you post (edit in your question) all the reverent files so everyone has a clearer picture

Comment: @Bob Will do that now.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question? This is regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" per the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)